# How to save number from EditView in another integer in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm pretty new to android so I will try to explain this the best way I can,

so I have a EditView in an activity I created like this:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/num"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.129" />
```

and in my MainActivity.kt I save the number user input's like this:

```
val number = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.num)
```

but when I try to sum the number user input's with a number I declared in my code like this:

```
var summ = 1

summ += number
```

When I launch program I says this:

None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: public final operator fun plus(other: Byte): Int defined in kotlin.Int public final operator fun plus(other: Double): Double defined in kotlin.Int public final operator fun plus(other: Float): Float defined in kotlin.Int public final operator fun plus(other: Int): Int defined in kotlin.Ints public final operator fun plus(other: Long): Long defined in kotlin.Int public final operator fun plus(other: Short): Int defined in kotlin.Int

If anyone knows how I could save the number user input's with a number I save in my MainActivity.kt please let me know!

Answer (score 2):

Using this should work:

```
val number = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.num).text.toString().toInt()
```

Since `findViewById<EditText>(R.id.num)` returns a View not an Int.

Answer (score 1):

`summ` is an `Int` object, which represents an integer. `number` is an `EditText` object, which is a UI widget that (among other things) displays text and allows the user to change the contents of that text. I know that might sound pedantic, but the point is those are two completely different things and you can't just "add" them to each other, it's like saying `2 +` .

The other answers tell you how to get the `String` contents of the `EditText` (which you also can't add to a number), and how to convert a `String` to an `Integer` (now you can add them - if the conversion worked!) but this is a general concept you need to understand - it won't always be as obvious that two different types can't just be combined, and you'll have to find a way to get what you need. `someTextView.text` for example is **not** a `String`, and you need to call `toString()` on it if you want the basic text contents

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
val number = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.num).text.toString().toInt()
```